# Display certain values in excel if criteria is met

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have certain criteria in picture and need help with a formula to display the relevant date in another sheet if all other criteria is met.

[image]

if *D* and *E* is filled in to display the date that corresponds (*H*)

Comment: You can use Lookup Formula also,,.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=IF(NOT(AND(ISBLANK(D2), ISBLANK(E2))), H2, "")
```

Depending on the content of D2 and E2, you may need to substitute:

`AND(D2="", E2="")` for `AND(ISBLANK(D2), ISBLANK(E2))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use VLOOKUP formula also by testing both D2 and E2 as Non-Blank cells.

=If(and(D2<>"",E2<>""),Vlookup(D2,D2:I10,5,False),"")

**NB:** In this formula I'm counting the Data Range from Column D because to get the date I'm looking for the value in Column D, so that Column H is 5th.